# Virtual SAN in Linux

Tags: linux

I have 4 500GB disks in different servers (remote).. Is it possible to have a 2 TB drive mounted in a 5th server? Just like vmware VSAN..

I believe its possible in linux, but there are still lot of grey areas like, how the RAID will be handled?
what if one disk fails? ..if anyone have any exp with this, please chip in..

Thanks in advance for your help!

- Kin

Comment: FreeNAS OS is thinkable ?

Comment: Can we make NAS work as SAN?

Comment: Lets omit freenas, openfiler etc, the problem is clear...we have 4 diff servers with 500 GB HD space, the question is how we can mount one drive in a 5th or one of the 4 servers as one 2 TB drive? literally, a virtual SAN..Hyper-V and vmware provides solutions for this, is there a similar one opensource in linux?

Comment: Have a look at Ceph? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceph_(storage) this would let all of your servers use that storage.

Comment: If you got 4 disks not used, why not plugging them together on a nas that support like iscsi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about Ceph? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceph_(storage) This would let you gave a cluster storage that all the servers could use. The client has been in the Linux kernel for some time, the server needs a newer kernel. You need xfs or btrfs for the underlying file systems. It may not be quite production ready, read up on it.

It's the nicest way I can think of to use the space, but you don't even mention what OS you are running (you imply Linux...), out much other details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is what I was looking for..but like you said, it may not be production ready..I did not mention a flavor because I wanted to know if this can be done any flavor. I will be working on Ubuntu 14.1...For those who did not get my question, I apoligize, please do let me know what other information is required. Thanks again for all the comments!!